# I am trying to make a timer in unity for reload using Time.deltaTime. Anyone know why this isn't working?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is the code, I'm not sure why this isn't working. I've done things very simmilar before.

```
    float limit = 1f;
    float i = 0f;

    if(hasResetReload == true && i < limit)
    {
        i += Time.deltaTime;
    }        
     else if(i == limit)
    {
        hasResetReload = false;
        anim.SetBool("Reload", false);
    }
```

Comment: can you update the post and add the whole class? also try this `else if(i >= limit)`

Comment: The value `Timedelta` is adding can pass `limit` without ever equaling it. change it to `i >= limit`

Answer (score 2):

When you write `i += Time.deltaTime;`, it will assign a 7 digit long float value to `i`. Now, when you say `i == limit`, it will have to match all 7 digits on both float which is almost impossible and never become true. You have to use `i >= limit`. So, it will become true whenever `i` become greater than or equal to `limit`.